# Some Major Knowledge Lack About Custom Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I got a custom array or list.Which is like :

```
final List<Haber> haberler = new ArrayList<Haber>();
```

Haber is my custom class.
I want to do :

```
listemiz.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder diyalogOlusturucu =
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),R.style.DialogTheme);

                    diyalogOlusturucu.setMessage(haberler[position])
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    diyalogOlusturucu.create().show();

                }
            });
```

but

```
haberler[position]
```

is not working as expected.
What can i do about that ?
All code of my project :
Haberler.java which hold these codes : https://gist.github.com/ShockvaWe/05fb28543032cc018778dedf5d9f4c04
Haber.java which is my custom class :
https://gist.github.com/ShockvaWe/ddf0cbd1ad766977ff28e4409ba51b4b

Comment: A List is not an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `haberler.get(position)`. See [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)).

Comment: I already tried it.It gives the error message which is "Cannot Resolve Method setMessage(upiynar.cback.Haber)".

Comment: @NickyRomero `setMessage()` of `AlertDialog.Builder` does not take an argument of type `Haber`. It does take an id or a `CharSequence` as an argument. See [AlertDialog.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMessage(int)) for more information.

Comment: I made it done working.Thanks.